# PHP 5.3.23 - PHP 5.6.3 - Zend framework 1.12 memory usage increase

Tags: php, zend-framework, memory, memory-leaks, mysqli

We've been running on PHP 5.3.23 for a while and have cron jobs that use a bit of memory due to objects and referencing. Most crons never exceeded the 128M though probably not even the 64M.

Since we upgraded to PHP 5.6.3 some of these crons use insane amounts of memory and still die, though they have not been changed. One of these crons surpasses 2GB of memory

Is there anything known that could cause this issue? Or does anyone have more information on how to debug it?

I've tried 
- putting everything in a function per loop call, so all references would be gone after the function,
- manual garbage collection
- unsetting objects manually
- xhprof with memory usage

it seems that it just keeps climbing up. Something makes me feel that it could be in the zend framework MysqlI Adapter

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is due to OpCache, which stores bytecode in shared memory.
It's enabled in php 5.6 by default. More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php).